# shacl validation error for a property which points to external file

Tags: python, validation, rdf, json-ld, shacl

data_file is at this url: https://schema.repronim.org/rl/activities/PHQ-9/items/phq9_8

I've written a shacl shape for the above data file. however, i get an error when i try to validate. In the above data file, the key `responseOptions` points to an external jsonld file --  which is when the error occurs. if i embed the external file in the data file itself, there is no error. 
I've used this shape for `responseOptions`:

```
 sh:property [
        sh:path reproterms:valueconstraints ;
        sh:or ( [ sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ] [ sh:node reproterms:ResponseOptionsShape ] ) ;
   ] .
```

The error thrown is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "validation/test.py", line 146, in <module>
    serialize_report_graph=True)
  File "/Users/sanuann/envs/trial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyshacl/validate.py", line 259, in validate
    do_owl_imports=False)  # no imports on data_graph
  File "~/envs/trial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyshacl/rdfutil/load.py", line 110, in load_from_source
    first_char = source[0]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Is the above shape correct? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your datatype constraint `sh:datatype sh:IRI` is off. The object of a `sh:datatype` triple must be an rdf datatype, such as `xsd:string`. I think you wanted to check for `sh:nodeKind sh:IRI`.

Comment: oops, that was a mistake! it doesn't work with `sh:nodeKind sh:IRI` either.

Comment: I see you reference the shape `reproterms:ResponseOptionsShape`. However, when I go to the URI for that prefix (`https://schema.repronim.org/rl/activities/PHQ-9/items/phq9_8` -> `https://schema.repronim.org/rl/contexts/generic` -> `https://schema.repronim.org/rl/terms/`), there is no RDF data to be found there. Are you sure your shacl processor should be able to find that shape? If you leave it out, does the data graph become valid?